# can not stop bots registration

Tags: php, bots

I'm developing an English learning web site and recently the site gets lots of bots registrations! You can see from here http://dev.englishpeer.com/newmembers.php.

I have increased the complexity of captcha one month ago. http://dev.englishpeer.com/register.php The bots seem pausing for a while and now come back again! Can anyone suggest a good solution for this headache problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try out reCAPTCHA project, which provides a more useful captcha:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha